# Rerender ng2-google-chart after programmatically changing the data

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I am using `ng2-google-chart` and it works fine. Now I want to use some checkboxes to choose which data is shown in the graph.

My graph is connected to the array `chartData`, which is updated correct after the selection. But the graph does not change. This is my graph

`<div #graph [chartData]="this.chartData" chartType="AreaChart" GoogleChart></div>`

Is there a way to rerender it after the data is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time I solved this:

In *angular2-google/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive.ts* import `OnChanges` and implment it like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  if (googleLoaded)
  {
    this.drawGraph(this.chartOptions,this.chartType,this.chartData,this._element);
  }
}
```

//edit: This is now fixed in the newest library version.