# Redraw ng2-google-chart on data change

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created my Gauge chart like this:

```
 public pieChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
    chartType: 'Gauge',
    dataTable: [
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Value', 80]
    ],
    options: {
      animation: {easing: 'out'},
      width: 350, height: 350,
      greenFrom: 60, greenTo: 100,
      minorTicks: 5,
      min: 0, max: 100,
      majorTicks: ['0', '20', '40', '60', '80', '100'],
      greenColor: '#d0e9c6'
    }
  };
```

I want to change the value from 80 -> 60 . I am not sure how to do that in my component and redraw the chart. I am using Angular-7.

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rerender ng2-google-chart after programmatically changing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206371/rerender-ng2-google-chart-after-programmatically-changing-the-data)

Comment: is your problem solved?